# How configure a static outbound IP for Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, nat, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have to sync some data via a static outbound IP that I need to whitelist with the data provider beforehand. For this reason, **I would like to configure a static outbound IP address for an ACI** (Azure Container Instance). If there is no cost-effective way of doing this I can also settle on configuring it for an App Service Web App, however, ACI is preferred due to resource isolation. (So one misbehaving worker cannot bring down the entire worker pool.)

For reference here is a simplistic graph of what I would like to achieve. For simplicity, I added both Web Apps and ACI to the image, but I only need one of them, preferably ACI.

[image: simplified graph of desired solution]

I have read through the relevant Microsoft docs in the last few days so I know multiple ways of doing this however, I am surprised that the official solution is way more complex and expensive than I think it should be.

The things I tried

- Configuring a NAT for an App Service Plan (works, but not desired)
- Deploying a firewall in front of vNet with ACIs (the "official" way)
- Configuring a NAT in front of a vNet with ACIs inside (Azure says not supported, but works)
- I also played around with App Gateway and Load Balancer but they only work with inbound IP addresses so not relevant to this question

**Configuring NAT for App Service Web Apps**
This works but it is not the desired solution. I can put a Web App into a subnet in a vNet and then configure a [NAT Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-overview) with a static IP address for that subnet. This works as expected, running

```
curl api.ipify.org.
```

inside the Web App will return the static IP address I configured in the NAT Gateway. The problem with this approach is that it uses Web Apps which has no resource usage isolation between apps on the same App Service Plan.

**Deploying a firewall in front of vNet with ACIs**
This is the "[official way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address)" suggested in the docs. (As a side note, I could never make it work following the guide, but that is not the main problem.) My main problem with this is complexity and price. We don't need a firewall, adding one and the burden of managing it is an extra complexity we don't need for this particular project. The price is also ridiculous, we want to configure a static outbound IP and the suggested way comes with a price increase bigger than we pay for the rest of the application. (We pay around ~400USD per month and a firewall starts at ~600$.)

So this is strongly not preferred.

**Configuring a NAT in front of a vNet with ACIs inside**
Their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#unsupported-networking-scenarios) explicitly state that this scenario doesn't work:

> **Virtual Network NAT** - Container groups deployed to a virtual network don't currently support using a NAT gateway resource for outbound internet connectivity.

However in fact it does work. Having a NAT configured for the subnet the container instance is in will make the ACI use the given outbound IP.

[image: ACI static outbound IP with NAT example]

I will open a question with the Azure Docs team about this also, but I am asking here as well. Do I misunderstand the documentation? Is this a supported scenario?

**So the question**
TL;DR; question is: **How to configure a static outbound IP for Azure Container Instances without using Azure Firewall?**

Do I approach the problem correctly?  Is there a different way of solving this problem? I am not a networking expert in general and neither in Azure, so I am pretty sure I am missing multiple possible solutions to this problem. I am interested in any solution that is relatively simple and doesn't add a significant cost overhead.

Comment: Related question for the MS docs team: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/81274

Comment: Really clear description of the issue and solutions that have already been tried. This should become an example of "how to write good question" :)

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with Azure directly (not via Github). The support engineer may be able to confirm if the "unsupported" solution that works is really unsupported or just doc running behind ever changing Azure landscape

Comment: You did not list how many apps there are but if only handful, you could run these in different app service plan for isolation and still pay less than what a firewall would cost

Comment: > Have you opened a support ticket with Azure directly (not via Github). 
Not yet, but I am planning to do so, just need to buy a support plan for the company first. As we don't have one at the moment.

Comment: > You did not list how many apps there are but if only handful, you could run these in different app service plan for isolation and still pay less than what a firewall would cost   

Yes, definitely, however that is still almost a 4x prices increase 30EUR vs 110EUR for the required configuration. So it can work in theory, but not preferred.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're focused on ACI; it's similar to many options and if you're looking at this from a security stand-point. It is no greater on the latter of options. You're truthfully best of from a cost point of view deploying where it works best for you and you may find many hosts that fail you. You should read more into public/private networks and group-policies as for scaling that's always on how stateless your code is. I run a 500 server army and if I was dead fixed on a solution, I'd be screwed... GL! :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If so, it would be beneficial if you shared it with us.

Comment: No, I have not found any official solution, I went with using the undocumented NAT gateway solution.

Comment: I can confirm that NAT gateway approach works like a charm!

Comment: Re-checking the docs, it seems the limiation has been removed in this commit: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/38579bf469df7aecea2cd5fecee1a6c97a521bd3. I assume this means it's officially supported now.

Answer (score 0):

**Official support has arrived!**

Confirmation:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/81273#issuecomment-1064347358

Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-nat-gateway